# Jagged fonts in Chrome with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

[image: Sample]My fonts appear jagged in Chrome in Windows 10.  I've enabled ClearType fonts, with no joy.

A number of forums have suggested going to chrome://flags and disabling DirectWrite, but this choice is not available.  Similarly "LCD text anti-aliasing" isn't available.

Where do I go next?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to go away when I reset all of the flags in chrome://flags. I might have made a change a while ago which worked, which stopped working with the latest Chrome update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a free Chrome extension to fix jagged chrome fonts: **[Chrome Font Super Enhancer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-font-super-enhance/ombebcdhklmmkcddekoplmobafpkolmd)**. It does the job pretty well!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).