# Google Chrome fonts are messed up on some websites

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, youtube, vimeo

I noticed recently the fonts used on some websites started to look worse. For example on vimeo https://vimeo.com/783454352:

[image]

Is it possible this is caused by installing a font locally on my computer? Likely helvetica fonts that I installed with a lot of different variations. If so, how can I find the culprit and delete that?

Youtube video fonts also look bad.

Comment: If you think it's caused by a font that you know go to `C:\Windows\Fonts` and delete it

Comment: Normally such errors are indeed caused by changes in the installed fonts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jagged fonts in Chrome with Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1585822/jagged-fonts-in-chrome-with-windows-10)